# How to integrate Gumroad API with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to see if a user is a paying customer for my gumroad product.  I'm trying to integrate the [Gumroad API](https://gumroad.com/api#resource-subscriptions) to Google Apps Script.

I have the following code

```
function checkAccount(){
  var token = <<token>>;
  var userEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var url = "https://api.gumroad.com/v2/sales";
  var headers = {"access_token=" : token};

  var options = {
    "method" : "GET",
    "email" : userEmail,
    "headers" : headers
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var jsonObject = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  Logger.log(jsonObject);

}
```

I get the following error `Exception: Request failed for https://api.gumroad.com returned code 401` which Gumroad is telling me `401 Unauthorized you did not provide a valid access token.`  I've checked the token and it's correct.  I've logged the options and headers, and they show up correctly.
I'm just not sure why it's giving me a 401.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing headers to this:

```
var headers = {
    "Authorization": `access_token=${token}`
};
```

EDIT:
Based on [this](https://leerob.io/blog/gumroad-node-api) you could try:

```
headers: {
  Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`}
```